# Cannot create a process in a COM object from an asp site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic, com

I'm updating an old process that already exists, which works as follows:

The user submits a form which runs the following asp (simplified, names changed):

```
    <%  
    set rb = Server.CreateObject("RecordBuilder.SomeObject")  
    rb.Calculate()  
    rb.StartProcess()  
    %>
```

The `RecordBuilder.SomeObject` was an old VB6 DLL, I don't have VB6, so I converted it to VB.NeT 4.0

The call to `Calculate()` works as expected, the call to `StartProcess()` fails.

`StartProcess()` is the following:

```
Public Function StartProcess()
    Try
        strProcess = "Starting process"
        Dim proc = New Process()
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\App\RecordProcessor.exe"

        Dim procHandle = proc.Start()
        strProcess = "Started process"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 9999, "RecordBuilder.SomeObject", strProcess & " failed: " & ex.Message & "<hr />Stack Trace:<br />" & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Function
```

This fails with the call to `proc.Start()`, however if I copy the test ASP to a `.vbs` file it will work as expected.

I have changed the permissions on `d:\App\RecordProcessor.exe` to grant execute permission to the group `Everyone`.

Comment: What exception do you get thrown?

Comment: Got it working.  I regenerated my Strong Name Key from within Visual Studio instead of via "sn -k".  In addition, if RedirectStandardOutput, UseShellExecute, and CreateNoWindow are not all set correctly, it tries to run the application in a Window and fails with access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the website's anonymous user account has the requisite permissions on the `d:\app` folder and any other folders that it may be touching.

One thing I notice that's missing is `proc.WaitForExit()` after your `proc.Start()`.

You probably want that so you can capture errors from the process itself as well:

```
Dim stdError As New String
Try
    strProcess = "Starting process"
    Dim proc = New Process()
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\App\RecordProcessor.exe"

    Dim procHandle = proc.Start()
    strProcess = "Started process"

    proc.WaitForExit()

    stdError = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    If stdError.Length > 0 Then
       '' So long since I did VB so next line might need tweaked
       Err.Raise(vbObjectError, "Caught StdError", stdError)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 9999, "RecordBuilder.SomeObject", strProcess & _
         " failed: "  & ex.Message & "<hr />Stack Trace:<br />" & ex.StackTrace)
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks, I have given the whole D:\app folder read & execute permission for the "Everyone" group.  I am using proc.WaitForExit() in my actual method, but I'm using a test method to troubleshoot the proc.Start call.  It throws an Exception on the proc.Start() call, so there would be nothing to read from StandardError

Comment: @user - what exception is thrown?